# Changed the system wide file-max, then got "Too many open files in system"

Tags: linux

I changed the file `/etc/sysctl.conf`, and the line `fs.file-max = 2048`, then `sysctl -p`.

Now, I can't do all thing, because of the error "Too many open files in system".

So how can I reset it? I even can't reboot my VPS.

Comment: Can't you just perform a reboot from the VPS hosting console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can only hard reboot the server, once you hard rebooted that VPS, you need to reset the setting as soon as you login before all available open files occupy again (remove `fs.file-max=2048` from `/etc/sysctl.conf` and then `sysctl -p`)